# Writing JSON stringified JS object into excel file and keeping the format

Tags: javascript, json, sheetjs

I am using SheetJS library to write an output into excel. This is how I create the WS:

```
var WSdata = [];
WSdata.push({test: "Test unsucessfull",
                expectedObj: JSON.stringify(expectedObj),
                testedObj: JSON.stringify(testedObj),
                difference: JSON.stringify(c.difference([expectedObj], [testedObj]))
              });
```

Then I append this WS to the newly created Excel file and save it as .xlsx file:

```
var newWS = xlsx.utils.json_to_sheet(WSdata);
      xlsx.utils.book_append_sheet(newWB, newWS, 'TEST DATA')   
      xlsx.writeFile(newWB, 'Test EXCEL.xlsx');
```

The problem is that the stringified variables (objects) are written as one line in the Excel cell. Using optional parameters in `JSON.parse` such as `JSON.parse(obj, null, 4)` doesn't help.

Thanks for suggestions

Comment: which format are you talking about ?

Comment: @AbishekKumar I want to keep the classic object formatting with line breaks instead of having it on one line.

Comment: did you try removing the `JSON.stringify`

Comment: @AbishekKumar this doesn't print anything to the excel. You can't pass JS object to the library.